# how can i seperate date and time for this format 2017-04-11T10:20:46.000+0000 in swift3

Tags: string, date, time, swift3, split

i have a date and time   2017-04-11T10:20:46.000+0000 like this format its coming from backend.

so i failed to seperate date and time from this format

so what i need exactly is,

from this 2017-04-11T10:20:46.000+0000 format i need like this

date :   2017-04-11
time :   10:20:46

i tried these many solution even though failed.

```
    let dateString = currentUser.dob
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "Yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss +zzzz"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")

    let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString!)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!))")

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: currentUser.dob!)
    print("Dateobj: \(dateObj!)")



    let myDate = currentUser.dob
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:myDate!)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:date)

    print("\(dateString)")
```

can somebody help me please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the milliseconds in your dateFormat.
The code below has been tested in a playground and gives the requested format:

```
let dobString = "2017-04-11T10:20:46.000+0000"
let dobDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dobDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let dob = dobDateFormatter.date(from: dobString) ?? Date()

let yearMonthDayFormatter = DateFormatter()
yearMonthDayFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
yearMonthDayFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
let dateString = yearMonthDayFormatter.string(from: dob)

let hourMinuteSecondFormatter = DateFormatter()
hourMinuteSecondFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
let timeString = hourMinuteSecondFormatter.string(from: dob)
```

Also make sure you set up the timezone of your DateFormatter if you are not in GMT.